# Copying files to a directory shared via ACL doesn't get default mask

Tags: linux, files, permissions, file-copy, acl

I'm trying to setup a simple shared directory on an ext4 filesystem for a group of users to work on.

Let's say I just need to give all permissions to all users belonging to the group "workgroup" to the directory `/home/shared`.

I tried with ACLs, by doing the following

```
chgrp workgroup /home/shared/
setfacl -m g:workgroup:rwx /home/shared/
setfacl -dm g:workgroup:rwx /home/shared/
```

and everything seems to work just fine with the exception of copying new files. In fact, if one user copies a new file, the permissions are:

```
# file: /home/shared/copied_file
# owner: testuser
# group: workgroup
user::rw-
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
group:workgroup:rwx             #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

Is there a way to fix this?